# aws hosting error with ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have hosted a ror app in aws ec2. Development env works fine but when i start production mode it says - "We're sorry, but something went wrong.We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."

I chechked production.log
production.log

```
[2015-07-02T16:37:21.257777 #12834]  INFO -- : Migrating to <Table Name> (20150608154559)
```

Like this all table name are shown with a migrating msg.

Is this is an error? How to resolve this ?

Comment: could you please show me the nginx `error.log` file's last 20-30 lines?

Comment: I hosted it via passenger. There is no ngnix

Comment: passenger is the app server. nginx web server. If you are not using nginx server then I believe you're using apache.

Comment: Its an ruby on rails app, i foll0wed this "http://dennissuratna.com/rails-deployment-aws2/" to host it. there was no apache in it. When i logged to my /var/log i can see these-alternatives.log    boot.log               cloud-init.log  dpkg.log    landscape  syslog.2.gz  unattended-upgrades
alternatives.log.1  btmp                   dist-upgrade    dpkg.log.1  lastlog    syslog.3.gz  upstart
apt                 btmp.1                 dmesg           fsck        syslog     syslog.4.gz  wtmp
auth.log            cloud-init-output.log  dmesg.0         kern.log    syslog.1   udev         wtmp.1

Comment: In this post they are showing they are downloading `binary nginx`. In your server terminal run `locate nginx` to find where it is installed.

Comment: This is the output of locate nginx-/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/passenger-install-nginx-module
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/build/nginx.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/buildout/support-binaries/nginx-1.8.0
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/dev/vagrant/nginx.conf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82329/discussion-between-emu-and-dips).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running its production mode in localhost where it displayed the error was due to secret_key_base.